# When MetaMask removes the Cancel button for a transaction?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, metamask, blocks, transaction-propagation

When I start a transaction, MetaMask shows it with Cancel button.

When does this Cancel button disappear? Maybe after one confirmation? After N (what is N?) confirmations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MetaMask removes the "cancel" (as well as "speed up") button as soon as the node they are running (which is Infura) sees that the transaction has been mined.

Comment: Then how does Infura see it? Does it wait for the first confirmation? or whatever? How to catch this moment from my `web3.js` code?

Comment: They use an RPC call to get the state of the chain. https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API